# Delete an item in localStorage after reload

Tags: javascript, html, dom, local-storage

I have store all the item/tasks  in `localStorage.setItem('saved',  newd[0].innerHTML)`   as the `createTask` function is executed so when the page reloads, if is not deleted than it remains saved. What I want is to be able to delete that single item as `removeButton` is clicked without affecting other items. It works before the page reloads but if more that one task is created, since all get store under the same `saved` name in localStorage, all get deleted. How could I delete the selected one without affecting the other items and still be able to do it after reloading the page?

```
let ids1 = document.getElementById('ids')
let ids2 = document.getElementById('ids2')

let buttonCreateTask = document.getElementsByClassName('create')
let newd = document.getElementsByClassName('newd')

let prevContent = localStorage.getItem('saved');
if (prevContent) { newd[0].innerHTML = prevContent}

function createTask (){ 

let paro = document.createElement('p')
paro.innerText = ids1.value + '\n' + ids2.value

let removeButton = document.createElement('button')
removeButton.innerHTML = 'REMOVE' 

paro.appendChild(removeButton)

removeButton.onclick = function() {
    paro.remove()
    localStorage.removeItem('saved')
   
}

if(ids1.value !== ''){ 
    if(ids2.value !== ''){ 
        
        newd[0].appendChild(paro)
ids1.value = ''
ids2.value = ''

localStorage.setItem('saved',  newd[0].innerHTML) 

    }else {
       alert('mising description')
    }
}else {
     alert('misning value')
}

buttonCreateTask[0].addEventListener('click', createTask )
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't use `removeItem()`. Since you've removed the DIV, you can just save the updated `innerHTML` to local storage.

Comment: I would use a self-invoking function that if the item exists in local storage it removes it and if it does not, it does nothing. That way whenever the JavaScript is rendered it will remove it.

Comment: @Wayne  great now it works the item selected is removed but after reload ```removeButton``` stops working for the ones that have been store, any idea on how to delete them?

Answer (score 0):

When you save `paro.innerHTML`, only the HTML is stored, not the inline JS. So when you reload the buttons, there are no event handlers.

You can use `newd[0].childNodes.forEach(...)` (after adding the `innerHTML`) to add event listeners.

```js
x = document.body;
x.innerHTML = '<button>a</button><button>b</button><button>c</button>';
x.childNodes.forEach((e) => e.onclick = show);

function show(t) {console.log(this.innerText);this.remove();}
```